# I want to use bootstrap collapse in table row, but it is working like toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap collapse in table to display data in row. When user click in particular row, it will expand the row and display some more information. But when user click on any other row it will expand, expanded row information will be invisible. But it is not happening. It is working like toggle

my code is :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>points</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {% for post in posts %}
            <tr>

             <td> 
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="detail" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{post.Driver.driverId}}"> {{post.Driver.driverId}}
                    </a>  
                   </h4>
                  </div> 
                  <div id="{{post.Driver.driverId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">  {{post.Driver.givenName}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>    
           </td>
             <td>
                  {{post.Driver.givenName}} &nbsp; {{post.Driver.familyName}}
            </td>
            <td>{{post.points}}</td>

           </tr> 
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: It slides up and down fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztf8wuf3/). Is this working for you? As a note: You're missing to close your row in `th` correctly.

Comment: But I need to use loop  to create row element. That part is toggling actually not collapsing. I i used div element , it is working fine.

Comment: updated the previous poster's fiddle to use two rows here, seems to work as I expect a collapse to work... https://jsfiddle.net/ztf8wuf3/1/